# Oracle constraint

Tags: oracle

Can I add a check constraint which makes sure that all values are unique, but allow duplicates of a default value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this using a funcction-based index (FBI):

```
create unique index idx on my_table (case when col != 'DEFAULT' then col end));
```

That creates a unique index on all values except 'DEFAULT'.

Comment: This is the correct approach, just note that you need to grant query rewrite for FBI's to work.

Comment: The requirement for query rewrite has not existed since 8i.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, have no idea why that thought stuck with me all this time. Live and learn