# Conditional Unique Contraints On Multiple Columns

Tags: database, oracle, constraints, unique-constraint

How to add a conditional unique constraint on table `prod_name` and `prod_type` columns of `products` table.

I would like to create constraint only when `prod_type = 'LOCAL'`

How could I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915063/oracle-constraint/7915112#7915112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood right, you want this:

```
  create unique index products_name_ui 
    on products (case when prod_type = 'LOCAL' then prod_name else null end);
```